# Associations not loaded in before_destroy callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

I have a simple `User` & `Account` model. I want to prevent deletion of an account if it has users attached to it. I create one `User` and one `Account` and associate them. Then, I do `Account.find(x).destroy` at the console. The account gets destroyed!

Notes:

1. User's `account_id` is correct.
2. `Account.find(x).users.empty?` at console returns `false`
3. `Account.find(x).destroyable?` at console returns `true`
4. `users.empty?` in `def destroyable?` returns `true` !!

I'm doing something wrong? What is it?

Code (Rails 3.2.9 on Ruby 1.9.2-p290):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessible :name
  before_destroy :destroyable?

  def destroyable?
    if users.empty? # This returns true when called via callback.
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 7):

So, turns out this is yet another Rails pitfall.

Solution is to move the `before_destroy` above the `has_many` call.

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/670
- https://github.com/lifo/docrails/commit/79cbfc8

@Yves Senn, you are right. I will avoid it from now on.
Using `dependent: :restrict` instead of `dependent :destroy`, which in this case, eliminates the need for my `before_destroy` callback.

Comment: In the past days I worked on several rails bugs, which were related to the order of your definitions inside the model. I highly suggest to put the callback definitions always after the associations.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is `dependent: :destroy`. If you don't want to destroy accounts with associated users, you should not add the dependent option.

Also this is very risky, since it could accidentally destroy users.